# UUID record are not fetch by mysql

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am using the UUID for userid in users tables and when I try to fetch all users it's show me like this.

```
 `RowDataPacket {
       id: <Buffer 34 33 33 32 34 61 63 35 2d 2d 36 33 32 2d 32 2d>,
       avatar_url: 'null',
       display_name: 'user_43324a'
     },
    RowDataPacket {
       id: <Buffer 34 33 33 32 34 61 63 35 2d 36 33 32 32 2d 34 34>,
       avatar_url: 'null',
       display_name: 'user_43324a'
    }`
```

And when I try to fetch 5f447700-4577-4547-a2b0-b8d1d7fbbe2b with this id it 'say record not found and it try to insert same userid again and got the duplicate key error.

Table structure ->

```
 | users | CREATE TABLE `users` (

  `id` binary(16) NOT NULL,

  `avatar_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,

  `display_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

Expected result -> I need to check if user present than ignore otherwise create a new user. but it's unbale to fetch added user by UUID.

Mysql version 8x

Node js version 14x

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your MySQL table definition. What data type is the `id` column?

Comment: @MarkB i mention my table structure in description please check

Comment: Also please reread your post, then hit [edit] and fix all those [markdown errors](/markdown), as well as things that clearly don't belong in your post, like that `your text` fragment.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for suggestion. can you check now it's little bit better?

Comment: still some rogue backticks and indentation issues, but much better, yes. Do note that Node 14 is a "dead" version now though - the current LTS is 18, and the current active version is 20 (16 went end-of-life a few days ago). That said though, your records and table schema show an `id` that is 16 characters long, but `5f447700-4577-4547-a2b0-b8d1d7fbbe2b` is 36 characters long, so that's definitely going to be a problem. The value you're talking about is _not_ going to be in that table.

Comment: Edit your question to include your NodeJS code doing the user query. Also, why is this also tagged with `php`?